# What options are the for streamers to receive money without disclosing their personal data?

Tags: donation, gifts

For a small streamer is there any way without having the need of opening a company to be able to receive money without disclosing their personal information like name and address?

I know some other topics about this, but this is more specific and not target at PayPal but rather any services that would allow for such.

With PayPal it would be possible if you have premium, however that option does not exist in every Country, so I was looking for a more generic solution if one exists.

Comment: Streamer as in YouTube, TikTok, etc?

Comment: @RonJohn as in  Twitch, YouTube, etc yes.

Comment: "without disclosing their personal information like name and address".  Are you referring to the streamer's personal information?

Comment: with those services, even if you bother to open a corporation, **they just ignore that and get the personal name/address/numbers of the actual beneficiary**.  it's completely impossible.

Comment: Get paid in cryptocurrency?